# Custom UITableViewCell shadow disappears

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell created in a xib that contains an "inner" view that I set a shadow on. I set the shadow in tableView willDisplayCell and it works initially

The problem is, when I scroll down, then back up, the shadow is gone (EDIT: it reappears when reloadData is called). What is happening here? Why isn't my shadow always shown?

More info:

- I've tried setting the shadow in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and I get the same result.
- I'm setting the cells selectionStyle and backgroundColor just prior to setting the shadow.
- I'm also curving the edge of the inner view just before setting the shadow (and this works all the time.. even after scrolling).
- My tableView is in a storyboard and I register the custom cell nib in my view controllers viewDidLoad.

Comment: Apple recommends to use CGPath (rather than just `shadowOffset` to improve shadow drawing performance. Did you try this?

Comment: Yep, I've tried using CGPath.. still happens

Comment: Consider using an image - that should perform better in any case.

Comment: looks like it wasnt a performance issue.. a bad constraint was clipping the bottom of my view (i.e. clipping the shadow)

Answer (score 0):

To debug, I increased the size of the curved edge and I can see that the shadow is still shown, but the bottom of my view is being clipped..

Looks like there is a bad or missing constraint somewhere..